# How to automatically break down the description of a command?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

I found the following description of a command which sets up which items must appear in the status line, [here](https://www.vi-improved.org/recommendations/):

```
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w[%L][%{&ff}]%y[%p%%][%04l,%04v]
"              | | | | |  |   |      |  |     |    |
"              | | | | |  |   |      |  |     |    +-- current column
"              | | | | |  |   |      |  |     +-- current line
"              | | | | |  |   |      |  +-- current % into file
"              | | | | |  |   |      +-- current syntax
"              | | | | |  |   +-- current fileformat
"              | | | | |  +-- number of lines
"              | | | | +-- preview flag in square brackets
"              | | | +-- help flag in square brackets
"              | | +-- readonly flag in square brackets
"              | +-- modified flag in square brackets
"              +-- full path to file in the buffer
```

---

I would like to reproduce the same sort of diagram which is used here to break down the description of other commands that I could find in the future. But drawing the `|`, `+` and `-` characters can take some time.

How to automate the process, so that I can focus on the contents of the description, rather than the diagram?

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I'm currently using to do it:

```
nno <silent> m<cr>   :<c-u>call <sid>break_down_mark()<cr>
nno <silent> m<bs>   :<c-u>call <sid>break_down_clear()<cr>
nno <silent> m<tab>  :<c-u>call <sid>break_down_draw()<cr>

fu! s:break_down_clear() abort
    if exists('s:bd_marks')
        call matchdelete(s:bd_marks.id)
        unlet s:bd_marks
    endif
endfu

fu! s:sort_coords(x,y) abort
    return a:x.col - a:y.col
endfu

fu! s:break_down_draw() abort
    if !exists('s:bd_marks.coords')
        return
    endif

    let ve_save = &ve
    set ve=all

    let coords   = s:bd_marks.coords
    let nr_lines = len(coords)

    call append(line('.'), repeat([''], nr_lines + 1))

    if exists(':Commentary')
        for j in range(0, nr_lines)
            +
            call setline(line('.'), "\<c-a>")
            Commentary
            call setline(line('.'), substitute(getline('.'), "\<c-a>", '', ''))
        endfor
    endif

    let loclist = []
    for i in sort(coords, 's:sort_coords')
        exe 'norm! '. i.line .'G'
        exe 'norm! '. i.col . '|j'
        for j in range(1, nr_lines)
            norm! r|j
        endfor
        exe 'norm! R+-- '

        call add(loclist, {
                          \ 'bufnr': bufnr('%'),
                          \ 'lnum' : i.line + nr_lines + 1,
                          \ 'col'  : i.col + 4,
                          \ })
        let nr_lines -= 1
    endfor

    call setloclist(0, loclist)
    lfirst

    call s:break_down_clear()
    let &ve = ve_save
endfu

fu! s:break_down_mark() abort
    if !exists('s:bd_marks')
        let s:bd_marks = {
                         \ 'coords'  : [],
                         \ 'pattern' : '',
                         \ 'id'      :  0,
                         \ }
    else
        if s:bd_marks.id
            call matchdelete(s:bd_marks.id)
            let s:bd_marks.pattern .= '|'
        endif
    endif

    if !empty(s:bd_marks.coords) && line('.') == s:bd_marks.coords[-1].line

        if count(s:bd_marks.coords, {
                                    \ 'line' : line('.'),
                                    \ 'col' : virtcol('.'),
                                    \ })
            call filter(s:bd_marks.coords, "v:val != {
                                                     \ 'line' : line('.'),
                                                     \ 'col' : virtcol('.'),
                                                     \ }")
        else
            let s:bd_marks.coords += [{
                                      \ 'line' : line('.'),
                                      \ 'col'  : virtcol('.'),
                                      \ }]
        endif

    else
        let s:bd_marks.coords  = [{
                                  \ 'line' : line('.'),
                                  \ 'col'  : virtcol('.'),
                                  \ }]
    endif

    let s:bd_marks.pattern = '\v'
                           \ .join(
                           \       map(
                           \           deepcopy(s:bd_marks.coords),
                           \           "'%'.v:val.line.'l%'.v:val.col.'v.'"
                           \          ),
                           \       '|'
                           \      )

    let s:bd_marks.id = !empty(s:bd_marks.coords)
                        \   ? matchadd('SpellBad', s:bd_marks.pattern)
                        \   : 0
endfu
```

---

**How to use it**

The previous code installs 3 key bindings:

```
m Enter        mark the current character as the starting point of something
               you want to describe

m Backspace    delete all the marks

m Tab          draw the diagram (`|`, `+`, `-`) for all the characters which
               were marked; also, populate the location list of the current
               window with their positions
```

After you hit `m Tab` to draw the diagram, you can navigate between the different parts of your description with `:lnext` and `:lprevious`, or any key bindings bound to these commands. As an example, [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) binds them to `[l` and `]l`.

A typical workflow would be to:

- mark the characters in which you're interested on a given line, hitting `m Enter` on each of them
- hit `m Tab` to draw the diagram
- navigate between the different parts of your command with `:lnext`/`:lprevious`

---

**How it works**

```
nno <silent> m<cr>   :<c-u>call <sid>break_down_mark()<cr>
nno <silent> m<bs>   :<c-u>call <sid>break_down_clear()<cr>
nno <silent> m<tab>  :<c-u>call <sid>break_down_draw()<cr>
```

These lines install the 3 key bindings described earlier. They call the 3 functions `s:break_down_mark()`, `s:break_down_clear()` and `s:break_down_draw()`.

---

```
fu! s:break_down_clear() abort
    if exists('s:bd_marks')
        call matchdelete(s:bd_marks.id)
        unlet s:bd_marks
    endif
endfu
```

This function is responsible for deleting all the information which were stored concerning the characters marked so far (`unlet s:bd_marks`). It also removes the highlighting which was applied on them (`call matchdelete(s:bd_marks.id)`).

---

```
fu! s:sort_coords(x,y) abort
    return a:x.col - a:y.col
endfu
```

This function will be needed to sort the coordinates of the characters you mark, because it's possible that sometimes you go back on the line, to mark a character you forgot.

If you have the lambda feature (`:echo has('lambda')` returns 1), then you could get rid of it. But in this case, you will have to replace the line:

```
for i in sort(coords, 's:sort_coords')
```

... with:

```
for i in sort(coords, {x,y -> x.col - y.col})
```

---

```
fu! s:break_down_mark() abort
    ...
endfu
```

This function is responsible for marking the current character as the start of an item in your future description.

```
if !exists('s:bd_marks')
    let s:bd_marks = {
                     \ 'coords'  : [],
                     \ 'pattern' : '',
                     \ 'id'      :  0,
                     \ }
else
    if s:bd_marks.id
        call matchdelete(s:bd_marks.id)
        let s:bd_marks.pattern .= '|'
    endif
endif
```

This checks whether the script-local variable `s:bd_marks` exists. If it doesn't, it means you're marking the first character in a line. So, it initializes the dictionary `s:bd_marks` with 3 keys:

- `coords`,  initial value = empty list
- `pattern`, initial value = empty pattern
- `id`,      initial value = zero number

`coords` will store the coordinates of your marks inside dictionaries. Each of them will contain 2 keys: `line` and `col`. Their values being the line address and the column number of the character which is being marked.

`pattern` will store the pattern describing all the characters you've marked. It will be used by the `matchadd()` function to highlight them.

`id` is the identifier of the match created by `matchadd()`. It's necessary to be able to delete it, either when when you've finished or when the match must be updated because you've just marked a new character.

If `s:bd_marks` does exist, then it means you're not marking the first character in a line. You're marking a subsequent one.
So, `s:break_down_mark()` removes the match (`call matchdelete(s:bd_marks.id)`), and it adds a bar character (`|`) at the end of the pattern, to prepare the next branch (`let s:bd_marks.pattern .= '|'`).
The latter will describe the position of the current character, which is being marked.

```
if !empty(s:bd_marks.coords) && line('.') == s:bd_marks.coords[-1].line
...
else
...
endif
```

This `if` block checks whether you're marking a character which is on the same line as the one containing the previous marked characters.

If you're marking a character on a different line, then the function resets the list of coordinates, with the ones of the current character:

```
    let s:bd_marks.coords  = [{
                              \ 'line' : line('.'),
                              \ 'col'  : virtcol('.'),
                              \ }]
```

Because it can't draw the diagram for characters across different lines. They must all be on the same line.

Otherwise, if you're marking a character on the same line, the function processes this sub-block `if`:

```
    if count(s:bd_marks.coords, {
                                \ 'line' : line('.'),
                                \ 'col' : virtcol('.'),
                                \ })
        call filter(s:bd_marks.coords, "v:val != {
                                                 \ 'line' : line('.'),
                                                 \ 'col' : virtcol('.'),
                                                 \ }")
```

This checks whether you're marking a character which was already marked. If it was, then the function removes its coordinates from the list `s:bd_marks.coords`.

This way, you can toggle the status of a mark, by hitting the same key binding `m Enter` multiple times on the same character.

If the character was not already marked, then the function adds its coordinates to `s:bd_marks.coords`:

```
        let s:bd_marks.coords += [{
                                  \ 'line' : line('.'),
                                  \ 'col'  : virtcol('.'),
                                  \ }]
```

Finally, the function creates the pattern describing all the characters which were marked so far:

```
let s:bd_marks.pattern = '\v'
                       \ .join(
                       \       map(
                       \           deepcopy(s:bd_marks.coords),
                       \           "'%'.v:val.line.'l%'.v:val.col.'v.'"
                       \          ),
                       \       '|'
                       \      )
```

And it creates a match to highlight them all:

```
let s:bd_marks.id = !empty(s:bd_marks.coords)
                    \   ? matchadd('SpellBad', s:bd_marks.pattern)
                    \   : 0
```

It colors the characters with the `SpellBad` highlighting group. If you don't like the color, you could replace `SpellBad` with the name of another group, after looking at the output of the `:hi` command.

---

```
fu! s:break_down_draw() abort
    …
endfu
```

This function draws the diagram.

```
if !exists('s:bd_marks.coords')
    return
endif
```

First, it checks whether `s:bd_marks.coords` exists. If the latter doesn't exist, the function doesn't do anything and returns, because without coordinates, it can't draw anything.

```
let ve_save = &ve
set ve=all
```

It saves the value of your `'virtualedit'` option, and gives it the value `all` so that it can draw freely.

```
let coords   = s:bd_marks.coords
let nr_lines = len(coords)

call append(line('.'), repeat([''], nr_lines + 1))
```

It opens some new lines. The number should be just enough to draw the diagram without overwriting existing lines which were just below the long command you want to break down.

```
if exists(':Commentary')
    for j in range(0, nr_lines)
        +
        call setline(line('.'), "\<c-a>")
        Commentary
        call setline(line('.'), substitute(getline('.'), "\<c-a>", '', ''))
    endfor
endif
```

This part comments the new lines which have just been opened. It relies on the custom command `:Commentary`, which is similar to the one defined in the [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) plugin. However, by default `:Commentary` doesn't comment an empty line, so the function temporarily inserts a random character (here `C-a`) before `:Commentary` is invoked, then it removes it.

If you don't use the `vim-commentary` plugin, but another one, check out its documentation to find the name of the Ex command which comments a line from a script. I could be wrong, but I think in [nerdcommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) it's `:NERDComComment`, and in [tcomment_vim](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) it's `:TComment`.
Then replace `:Commentary` accordingly.

```
let loclist = []
for i in sort(coords, 's:sort_coords')
    exe 'norm! '. i.line .'G'
    exe 'norm! '. i.col . '|j'
    for j in range(1, nr_lines)
        norm! r|j
    endfor
    exe 'norm! R+-- '

    call add(loclist, {
                      \ 'bufnr': bufnr('%'),
                      \ 'lnum' : i.line + nr_lines + 1,
                      \ 'col'  : i.col + 4,
                      \ })
    let nr_lines -= 1
endfor
```

This part is responsible for the creation of the list `loclist` which will be used to populate the location list of your current window. It also draws the diagram with these 4 commands:

```
exe 'norm! '. i.line .'G'    position the cursor on the line to break down

exe 'norm! '. i.col . '|j'   position the cursor on the column of a character
                             from which a branch of the diagram must be drawn

norm! r|j                    draw the bar characters inside the vertical part of the branch

exe 'norm! R+-- '            draw the `+--` horizontal part of the branch
```

If you don't like the `|`, `+` and `-` characters, and you prefer using different ones, you could change the last 2 commands.

```
call setloclist(0, loclist)
lfirst
```

This part populates the location list with `loclist` and positions the cursor on its first entry, so that you are automatically positioned below the first character that you marked.

```
call s:break_down_clear()
let &ve = ve_save
```

Finally, the function removes the highlighting which was applied on the marked characters, and restore the value of your `'virtualedit'` option.

---

**How it looks**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way of avoiding this is to simply build your statusline incrementally:

```
" filename (relative path)
set statusline=%1*%f\ 
" file format
set statusline+=%2*[%{&ff}]
" file type
set statusline+=%3*%y
" modified flag
set statusline+=%4*%m
" read only flag
set statusline+=%9*%r
" help file flag
set statusline+=%5*%h
" preview window flag
set statusline+=%5*%w
" buffer number (note trailing space)
set statusline+=%6*\ buf:%n\ 
" col number,line number / number of lines (note trailing space)
set statusline+=%7*[%v,%l/%L]\ 
" percentage through file
set statusline+=%8*[%p%%]
```

Comment: The `statusline` example is just for demonstration. Being able to automate drawing of ASCII art in this way is still useful in contexts when you *can't* break the line you're annotating up so easily.